# Program stops working when I input variables

Tags: c

I want to do something in case the username is equal to "admin", but this error appears when I input username and pass.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char UserName[100];
    char admin[6]="admin";
    double Password;
    int choice,result;
    while (choice!=3){
        printf("Username : ");
        scanf("%s",&UserName);
        printf("Password : ");
        scanf("%d",Password);
        char admin=admin;
        if(strcmp(UserName, admin)&&(Password==1234))
        {
            printf(" enter your choice : ");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to mention the error message, you are missing a bracket, you redefined admin, and strcmp takes two pointers as args.

Comment: You're using `choice` uninitialized.

Comment: `char admin[6]="admin";` then `char admin=admin;`?? Always compile with **warnings enabled** and do not accept code until it compiles without warning. For gcc/clang use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wshadow` for VS (`cl.exe`) use `/W3` (for other compilers, review the options -- they will all have similar warnings/levels to enable). Read and understand the errors/warnings (and notes). The compiler will tell you about problem code and the line and character where it occurs -- you can learn as much from your compiler as you can from most books.

Comment: You claim the program runs, but it doesn't even compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> this error appears when i input username and pass.

because you have these 2 undefined behaviors in your code :

> ```
> scanf("%s",&UserName);
> ```

whose must be

```
 scanf("%s",UserName);
```

and 'worst' :

> ```
> scanf("%d",Password);
> ```

whose must be

```
scanf("%d", &Password);
```

else `scanf` try to write to an undefined address being the value of *Password* which is not initialized

May be the execution continue after `scanf("%s",&UserName)` but no chance it does after `scanf("%d",Password)` producing typically a segmentation fault

Note also *Password* has to be an `int`, or the format has to be something like `"%g"` but to use a floating point value for a password is very improbable

Out of that you have an other undefined behavior in

> ```
> while (choice!=3){
> ```

because *choice* is never initialized, but that time the effect is not 'catastrophic' like it is with `scanf("%d",Password);`

Also what do you expect with :

> ```
> char admin=admin;
> ```

that line must be removed because there is no reason to have it

And finally a closing '}' is missing before `return 0;`

Comment: ... and `password` must be `int`. And many other problems.

Comment: @Jabberwocky ah yes true, I didn't see, thank you

Answer (score 2):

I tried to minimize the changes to your code. See my attempt of a possibly working (not tested) alternative

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {                   // full definition with prototype
    char UserName[100];
    char admin[6] = "admin";
    int Password;                  // changed to int
    int choice = 0, result;        // initialize choice
    while (choice != 3) {
        printf("Username : ");
        // limit input, the & is wrong, check the return value of scanf
        if (scanf("%99s", UserName) != 1) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        printf("Password : ");
        // match type of "%" and variable, check the return value
        if (scanf("%d", Password) != 1) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        // char admin = admin;     // deleted
        // strcmp returns 0 when the strings match
        if ((strcmp(UserName, admin) == 0) && (Password == 1234))
        {
            printf("OK!\n");       // do something
        }
        // block structure messed up?
        printf(" enter your choice : ");
        if (scanf("%d", &choice) != 1) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated your code with some things that were missing:

- Added string.h include that was required for strcmp
- Removed char admin = admin
- Updated the Password scanf to use the proper type

Always try to pay attention to the compiler and activate all warnings as errors when possible.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
   
int main()
{
   char UserName[100];
   char admin[6] = "admin";
   int Password;
   int choice = 0;
   while (choice != 3)
    {
       printf("Username : ");
       scanf("%s", UserName);
       printf("Password : ");
       scanf("%d", &Password);
       if (strcmp(UserName, admin) && (Password == 1234))
       {
           printf(" enter your choice : ");
       }
       return 0;
   }
}
```

Comment: `double` is a poor choice for `password`. I'd rather use `int` as equality comparisions between with `double` and `int` may go wrong.